# zigbee and embedded system

Tags: embedded, zigbee

I'm new with zigbee i need you to help me learn about it and know how to implement an embedded system using it
thanks in advance

Comment: That's a little too general... do you have a specific question?

Comment: where to start? is there any C++ libraries i can use ??

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: So update the question rather than hiding relevant information in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

One good place to look is on the [Digi](http://www.digi.com/technology/rf-articles/wireless-zigbee.jsp) site.  They have several products to help you, including embedded development kits.

If you want to go Open Source, look at Source Forge.  They have some open source stacks.  I have not used any of them, so I cannot comment beyond knowing that they exist.

Depending on your needs, you might want to just look at XBee, which is a subset of zigbee.  There are some nice development tools for XBee.  I have used an XBee expansion shield with the .net micro framework and boards provided by [TinyCLR](http://www.tinyclr.com/hardware/12/fez-cobra/#/list/4/) to do a wireless prototype.

Creating a zigbee stack on your own would be a fairly large task, so only you can determine if there is ROI in doing so.  I would be more inclined to buy it in.

Answer (score 0):

Get a *ZigBee Starter Kit*.  Lots of vendors provide one; gust Google that exact phrase.

For example: [AVR 8-Bit RISC - IEEE 802.15.4/ZigBee - Tools](http://www.atmel.com/products/zigbee/tools.asp?family_id=676)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can ZigBee on a PIC/Microchip at very low cost. http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2112